# Using grunt for front end with php

Tags: php, html, gruntjs

Forgive me, I'm new to Grunt and I don't typically code PHP. This is a new project for me. I'm trying to use Grunt, because it's awesome, with some html files that have minimal php in them. 
I originally installed the regular grunt, not the php grunt. Now I realize that maybe I should have installed grunt-php. However, I tried deleting the gruntfile.js, installing grunt-php, and then adding the new configurations to a new gruntfile.js but terminal keeps giving me a "default" not found error, even though the default task is definitely there. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. 
Is it easier to just add php to my original grunt file? I don't know how I would do that though. 
Here's the original file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
   require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
   grunt.initConfig({
       htmlhint: {
            build: {
               options: {
                    'tag-pair': true,
                    'tagname-lowercase': true,
                    'attr-lowercase': true,
                    'attr-value-double-quotes': true,
                    'doctype-first': true,
                    'spec-char-escape': true,
                    'id-unique': true,
                    'head-script-disabled': true,
                    'style-disabled': true
                 },
                 src: ['index.php']
             }
         },
         watch: {
             html: {
                 files: ['index.php'],
                 tasks: ['htmlhint']
            },
            js: {
                 files: ['assets/js/**/*.js'],
                 tasks: ['uglify']
             },
             css: {
                 files: ['assets/sass/**/*.scss'],
                 tasks: ['buildcss']
             }
         },
         sass: {
             build: {
                 files: {
                     'build/css/master.css': 'assets/sass/master.scss'
                 }
             }
         },
         browserSync: {
            /*bsFiles: {
                src : ['assets/css/*.css', '*.html'],
            },*/
             files: ['*.html', 'assets/templates/*.html'],
            options: {
                server: {
                    baseDir: "./"
                }
            }
        },
        cssc: {
            build: {
                options: {
                    consolidateViaDeclarations: true,
                    consolidateViaSelectors:    true,
                    consolidateMediaQueries:    true
                },
                files: {
                    'build/css/master.css': 'build/css/master.css'
                }
            }
        },

        cssmin: {
             build: {
                 src: 'build/css/master.css',
                 dest: 'build/css/master.css'
             }
        },

        uglify: {
            build: {
                files: {
                    'build/js/base.min.js':  ['bower_components/jquery/dis/jquery.min.js', 'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js', 'assets/js/**/*.js']
                 }
             }
         },
         pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
         phpunit:{
            test:{
                 dir:'',
                 options:{
                     bin: 'bin/phpunit',
                     configuration:'app/phpunit.xml'
                 }
             }
         },
         'sf2-cache-clear':{
              options: {},
              dev: {},
              prod: {}
          }
      }); 
      grunt.registerTask('buildcss',  ['sass', 'cssc', 'cssmin']);
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-phpunit');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-symfony2');
      grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'buildcss', 'browserSync','watch']);
     grunt.registerTask('test', ['phpunit:test']);

   };
```

Here is the grunt code I tried adding for grunt-php:

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig({
        php: {
        dist: {
             options: {
                 hostname: '127.0.0.1',
                 port: 9000,
                 base: 'dist', // Project root 
                 keepalive: false,
                 open: false
            }
        }
     },
     browserSync: {
         dist: {
             bsFiles: {
                  src: [
                      // Files you want to watch for changes 
                  ]
             },
            options: {
                proxy: '<%= php.dist.options.hostname %>:<%=php.dist.options.port %>',
                watchTask: true,
                notify: true,
                open: true,
                logLevel: 'silent',
                ghostMode: {
                     clicks: true,
                     scroll: true,
                     links: true,
                     forms: true
                 }
             }
         }
    },
       watch: {
          // Your watch tasks 
       }
   });

   grunt.registerTask('serve', [
     'php:dist',         // Start PHP Server 
     'browserSync:dist', // Using the php instance as a proxy 
     'watch'             // Any other watch tasks you want to run 
   ]);
   grunt.registerTask('default', ['php']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be way easier to add grunt-php to your existing Gruntfile.
First install it in your project:

```
npm install grunt-php --save-dev
```

Then add the task config in your Gruntfile (for example between pkg and php-unit):

```
php: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            base: 'build'
        }
    }
},
```

And finally define the task to run the server and default to build + serve:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', [
    'php:dist',
    'watch'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'buildcss', 'serve', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Ok I have php-unit installed and I have grunt-php installed. However when I change my index.html file to an index.php file and run grunt it runs without errors but the page just shows "Cannot GET /." Should it be doing that?

Comment: Is your php file in your `build` folder? That's what grunt-php is serving. If it is not, you need to copy it there. Also I had made an error in my php: task definition above, I edited my comment.